# How to resolve “Cannot find module” (custom module) error in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have my user.js file inside controller directory and utility.js file inside service directory.

In user.js, I am trying to access utility.js as below.

```
var Utility = require('./service/utility');

var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();
```

**error thrown by node.js**

```
Debugger listening on port 5858

 module.js:327

throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './service/utility'

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Comment: it seems that the path of `./service/utility` is not right,  `./service/utility` is a relative path. and I think you can try `../service/utility`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are `controller` and `service` adjacent directories like this?

```
+- service/
|   +- utility.js
|
+- controller/
    +- user.js
```

Relative paths in `require` are processed as relative to the current module.
So if your directories are laid out like that, you'll need to get the path *relative to `user.js`*:

```
var Utility = require("../service/utility");
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! My directory structure is exactly same as you mentioned and it worked.

Comment: PS:- If they are in same directory 
+- component/     utility.js, user.js

Use ./ to indicate same directory.